# I am creating a youtube downloader with tkinter and pytube, everything is fine until i goto download the file then i get the error

Tags: python

I am creating a youtube downloader with tkinter and pytube, everything is fine until I goto download the file then I get the error:

> "AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'streams'"

if anyone could please explain what I have done wrong I would really appreciate it

```
   import pytube
   from tkinter import *
   from pytube import YouTube
   from tkinter import messagebox




   def click():
       yt = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
       yt.pack()

       print(yt.streams.all())
       stream = yt.streams.first()
       stream.download()

  window = Tk()
  window.title("tubemaker")
  window.geometry("500x500")
  window.configure(background="black")


  l1 = Label(window, text="blank", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold")
  l1.pack()

  b1 = Button(window, text="Press the button to begin downloading your video", 
  width=70, command=click)
  b1.pack()

  window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `yt` is an `Entry` widget. Why do you think it has an attribute named `streams`?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do with `yt = Entry(...` there, but you should download with pytube like this:

```
yt = YouTube(LINK_TO_VIDEO) 
vid = yt.streams.first() 
vid.download(YOUR_FILENAME) # downloads into this file
```

Edit: for your case, you need to create the Entry and use `get()`:

```
import pytube
from tkinter import *
from pytube import YouTube
from tkinter import messagebox

def click():
    inp = input.get()
    yt = YouTube(inp)
    print(yt.streams.all())
    stream = yt.streams.first()
    stream.download()

window = Tk()
window.title("tubemaker")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.configure(background="black")


input = Entry(window)
input.pack()

l1 = Label(window, text="blank", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold")
l1.pack()

b1 = Button(window, text="Press the button to begin downloading your video",
width=70, command=click)
b1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: with the yt =  Entry, i am trying to make a tkinter app in which the user inputs the URL and presses the button to download the video, instead of running pytube through the command line or in idle

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out, i appreciate the help. the problem was i wasn't turning the tkinter input into a str object with (str(YT)